# Database Architecture: Multiple Type Relations

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm building a Laravel application that has "listings". These listings can be things like boats, planes, and automobiles; each with their own specific fields.

I will also have an images table that should relate to each type of listing and a users table that needs to map to each type of listing. I'm trying to determine the best way to map each listing type back to `images` and `users`.

One way I've thought of doing this was having separate `boats`, `planes` and `automobiles` tables with their specific fields and then having specific `boat_images` `plane_images` and `automobile_images` tables to map to each respective type. But then relating each type to a user would be a bit tricky.

I don't think one giant listing table with all fields I'd ever use through these 3 (which could grow in size later) would make sense --- and I also don't believe having a general metadata field that has a JSON object full of specifications for each listing would work well either when I want to have a searchable database.

I know of [pivot tables](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables), but I'm trying to grasp the overall architecture here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to separate images table. The images table can be a single table that can store your boats, planes and automobiles images. Laravel can handle it. See http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#polymorphic-relations to see example of code and idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a `listings` table, holding only `id` and `name`. Boats, planes, automobiles and others should be a subset table.

Each table will have its own entity. And the `Listing` entity will have multiple `hasMany` relationships with its subset tables. These relationships will be named like `boats()`, `planes()`, etc. Each subset listing entity will hold a single `belongsTo` relationship.

Using these subset tables should also help to compartmentalize form validation.

You can have a single `images` table and use a polymorphic relationship towards the listings table. This one is a huge savior.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tips! So as far as the `name` goes, do you mean the name of the subset table, or just the generic title that could be used to identify the item? In this case, I probably wouldn't have a title, as it would be auto-generated by the vehicle information selected. Thanks again!

Comment: I meant the generic title. You can go even further using polymorphic relationships to handle boats, planes, automobiles, etc.